# How to use ligth4j to operate mysql

Tags: light-4j

How to use ligth4j to operate mysql? The demo result from github seems incomplete. My project reference link is https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j

Answer (score 0):

Light4J doesn't implement anything to operate mysql, you could use directly the java libraries to do it (java.sql, javax.sql). If you need it, you could initialize a connection pool settings with StartupHookProvider and create your own MysqlStartupHookProvider 
(review the mongoDb example: https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j/blob/release/mongodb/src/main/java/com/networknt/database/db/MongoStartupHookProvider.java)